# Version 2.8/May 23 - Assemble multiple textures and export them in one single texture?

Tags: export

What I currently have =

- Blender 2.80 Beta Windows 64 Bit (May 23, 01:37:23, a1ad71304c2d) (portable version) (downloaded at https://builder.blender.org/download/) - What I see when I open it [image]
- file.obj (one model and multiple positioned jpeg textures inside the obj) + his file.mtl - What I see when I import my obj
  [image]

What I want =

- Please, I would like to assemble all the jpeg textures and export them in one single texture. Another way to say it "Join image textures into a single one upon export". Visual way to understand my question
  [image]

Please, consider (to not waste your time and mine) =

- The Blender version I am using.
- That I don't want 2/3 or more solutions to do it. I want 1 effective solution only.
- That I don't want tips to do it slower/faster.
- That I don't want to have a nicer Blender interface/menus/icons.
- That I don't want to edit my model.
- That I don't want to edit my textures.
- That I don't want to add more models or textures.
- That I don't want to make animation.
- That I don't want to add a lamp or a camera.
- That you don't need to share me videos or screenshot if your words are clear.
- That you don't need to share me tutorials/wiki pages if it doesn't answer my question.

Why I ask my question =

- I am looking for a simple answer to my question above because there is 3 millions of different tutorials with different Blender versions, for different solutions ("Bake" "Wrap" etc), situations and needs. A "visual way" to understand my question https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0qbL.jpg .

Thank you for your time and answers. I will give more information if you need.

B

NB : I already have searched online since 2 days. I do not come here because I didn't make some effort. I am frustrated at not being able to use such great software as Blender. I will record the steps/make a tutorial and post it to my Youtube channel.

Comment: What I see when I import my obj = https://i.imgur.com/ZIlCf95.jpg .

Comment: HI. Please upload images directly using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: You very clearly stated what you don't want but I'm not sure I got exactly what your do want. You are trying to join image textures into a single one upon export, right? Could you clarify that it in your question body?

Comment: Hello. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Here is a picture of my need. I have edited my thread => https://i.imgur.com/NONinM7.jpg (sorry Ray Mairlot I don't see any option to add my picture on stackexchange in comments fields).

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I have found the stackexchange image button. Sorry. I have edited the thread.

Comment: I think you are saying that you have many material slots assigned to your model, each with different textures associated with them. The different faces of your model are then using those different images to show, for example, an eye on some faces but a fingernail on some others. You are after one big image so that you can just map different faces to different parts of one image, rather than having lots of different images. Is that right?

Comment: Yes @edna it is exactly what I am looking for. Sorry to not be able to explain it clearly in my thread. Have you an idea to do that ? (Please if you advice me a tips, write also the Blender version you are using for)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a cheat, but I think this gives you the answer you need. Maybe there is a function that does this better, but at least it works ...

Once you have applied your textures, make them Emission shaders so that they will render as shadeless. Then bake the output using Cycles to create a single image map that contains them all combined into a single image.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot for all your answers! I'm gonna test that. Also I've seen the plugin CAT to make such need.